# WPF Binding Syntax Question

Tags: wpf, binding

The code below is supposed to show a stack of three list boxes, each containing a list of all the system fonts. The first is unsorted, and the second and third are alphabetized. But the third one is empty. I don't see any binding error messages in the VS Output window when debugging.

The markup is:

```
<Window x:Class="FontList.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FontList"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}" />
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SystemFonts}" />
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.SystemFonts}}" />
</Grid>
```

The code behind is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace FontList
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static List<FontFamily> SystemFonts { get; set; }

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            SystemFonts = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.OrderBy(f => f.ToString()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the third binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `SystemFonts` before you call `InitalizeComponent`. The WPF binding has no way of knowing the property's value changed.

```
public MainWindow() {
    SystemFonts = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.OrderBy(f => f.ToString()).ToList();
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

or better yet, use:

```
static MainWindow() {
    SystemFonts = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.OrderBy(f => f.ToString()).ToList();
}

public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bindings are created during `InitializeComponent`, while `SystemFonts` is `null`. After you set it, the binding has no way of knowing that the property's value has changed.

You can also set `SystemFonts` in a static constructor, which is probably preferable since it's a static property. Otherwise every instantiation of `MainWindow` will change the static property.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public static List<FontFamily> SystemFonts{get; set;}

    static MainWindow {
       SystemFonts = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.OrderBy(f => f.ToString()).ToList();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Since the Binding doesn't use the DataContext, I don't believe it matters when he sets that. SystemFonts would need to be set before the binding is even created (i.e. InitializeComponent).

Comment: @CodeNaked: I write fast first, then edit a few times. :) Fixed it prior to seeing your comment.